# Read only file system error while trying to install docker-compose on snappy Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-core, docker

How to install/use docker-compose on Ubuntu snappy?

when I run:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.2.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

from [docker tutorials](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)! i get this error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: Read-only file system
```

Comment: Hi Marco, have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install compose on the read only partition, you need to save it somewhere in `/home/ubuntu/apps/docker` for that to work.